# implementing search in asp.net MVC makes conflict with tinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I implement search form which I can search some question on it to see its answer in asp.net MVC, my search function works completely fine, I used `TinyMCE` Editor to edit my questions.

this is my model:

```
  public class Question
    {

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Qu { get; set; }

        [AllowHtml]
        [UIHint("tinymce_full_compressed")]
        public virtual string Ans { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }


    }
```

when I put for example `enter` between sentences, in my editing, it creates `</br>` tag and save on my database. after searching on text box, in result instead of rendering tags, it shows `</br>` tag. something like this `test<br />test` and shows it in browser instead of two `test` word in two different rows without `</br>` tag. it seems it can not translate the tags which editor added to the string.

. this image shows what happens
[image: what happens after searching strings]

here is my controller:

```
  public ActionResult Help(string searchString)
    {
        searchString = Request["search"];
        var repsearch = new RepositorySearch();
        List<Question> question = new List<Question>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            question = repsearch.GetAllQuestion().Where(n => n.Qu.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())).ToList();
        }
        return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? (ActionResult)PartialView("_QuestionPartial", question) : View(question);
    }
```

I think the problem relates to this `QuestionPartial`
here is my `QuestionPartial`

```
  @using iranhoidaytour_com.Models
  @if (Model.Count > 0)
{
<ul id="hs">
    @foreach (Question q in Model)
    {
        <li class="">
            <h5 class="quos">@q.Qu</h5>
            <p class="answ">@q.Ans</p>
        </li>

    }
  </ul>
 }
```

and this is my `TinyMCE` settings:

```
      <script>
   tinymce.init({
       selector: '#mytextarea',
  height: 500,
  theme: 'modern',
  force_br_newlines: false,
  force_p_newlines: false,
  forced_root_block: '',
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc'
  ],
  toolbar1: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample',
  image_advtab: true,
  templates: [
    { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
    { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
  ],
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
 });

    </script>
```

and here is my view

```
<div class="row" id="searchhelp">

    <div class="container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Help", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { @id = "FormSearch", @class = "form-group container" }))
        {

            @Html.TextBox("search", null, new { @class = "form-control col-md-10", @placeholder = "What Is Your Question?Enter Keyword!" })
    <button type="submit" class="left " id="btn-search">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
        }
    </div>

</div>




<div id="helpicons" class="container">


    <div id="tagsname">

        <div id="intagsname">
            @Html.Partial("_QuestionPartial", Model)
            <div class="ajaxloader1">
                <img class=""  src="~/Content/img/ajax-loader (4).gif" alt="Alternate Text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

Appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: the control the `test<br/>test` appear in use `@Html.Raw(@theValue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have to do to return markup that is not HTML encoded.:

```
<h5 class="quos">@q.Qu</h5>
   <p class="answ">@Html.Raw(q.Ans)</p>
```